# Simple products is not showing on Catalog page/Catalog search Magento 2.3.2

Tags: catalog, catalogsearch, magento2.3.2, simple-product

I am using Magento 2.3.2 for my store. I observed that all my simple products are not showing on the catalog page & catalog search (**Frontend**) . otherwise configurable products working correctly.

```
I have tried 
     -> re-indexing
     -> Save all simple products again.
     -> Clear cache stuff.
     -> Checked product configurations(Visibility,Stock & quantity etc.)
```

**but no luck.**

I have observed one weirdest thing when I am trying to run re-indexing then it shows me beloe output:

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
```

**Almost all the process took 00:00:00 time**

what should I do? Any suggestion?

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Please make sure product is assign to website and check the visibility of product for website and store

Comment: Please check also if the products are in stock.